# Error while accessing shared preferences of Android App's first run

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Whenever I run my Android app for the first time after installation and access the shared preferences, I get this system error -

```
remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.example.ap/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.appid.xml.bak
```

I am not able to figure out what this error means. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Code to access shared preferences -

```
String setOrNot;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("LastFetchTimeFile",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPref.contains("LastFetchTime"))
    {
        String lastFetchTime = sharedPref.getString("LastFetchTime", null);
        setOrNot = lastFetchTime;
    }
    else
    {
        setOrNot = "notSetYet";
    }
```

Comment: show the code that how are you accessing the Shared Preferences

Comment: Are you just running `getSharedPreferences`? Because that error is separate from your code.

Comment: I added the code to the question, the error goes when I remove this block of code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if condition, shared preference handles that for you. What i would do is

```
String setOrNot;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("LastFetchTimeFile",MODE_PRIVATE);

     setOrNot = sharedPref.getString("LastFetchTime", "notSetYet");
```

Also can you tell me which device/os ?