# Error while accessing Shared Preference of my App

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am not able to access shared preference data. I have already checked in another URL for this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843580/error-while-accessing-shared-preferences-of-android-apps-first-run). Error is...

```
remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.example.lenovo.sms/shared_prefs/refresh_token.xml.bak
```

Code for storing and accessing data in shared preference

```
private void saveToken(String recent_token) {
    saveTokenPref = getSharedPreferences(Config.SAVE_TOKEN_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveTokenPref.edit();
    editor.putString(Config.TAG_TOKEN,recent_token);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getSavedToken() {
    saveTokenPref = getSharedPreferences(Config.SAVE_TOKEN_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String saved_token = saveTokenPref.getString(Config.TAG_TOKEN,"");
    Log.d("save token",saved_token);
    return saved_token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()`:

```
saveTokenPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Then, use the below codes:

```
private void saveToken(String recent_token) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveTokenPref.edit();
    editor.putString("token",recent_token);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getSavedToken() {
    String saved_token = saveTokenPref.getString("token","");
    Log.d("save token",saved_token);
    return saved_token;
}
```

Hope this helps.